# How Can i Know if GKAchievement is Completed?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I have built objectives for my game and everything works just fine accept the part of making the objectives not be called any more after any of them is completed.

I know there is a Property of the `GKAchievement` Class "completed" which is a boolean that returns yes when the Achievement is 100 percent done.

here is the method that called when a Achievement is 100 percent done it passes id which is the Achievement identifier and report the acheeee :

```
- (void)AchivmentDidAchive:(id)Achivment{
NSString *identifier = Achivment;
NSLog(@"%@",identifier);
self.achivment = [[GKAchievement alloc]initWithIdentifier:identifier];
self.achivment.showsCompletionBanner = YES;


if (!self.achivment.completed) {
    self.achivment.percentComplete = 100;
    NSLog(@"Reproting!");
    [self.achivment reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error)
     {

     }];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Achivment Completed!");
}   }
```

what I am trying to do here is to set the percent completed to 100 and report it so in the next time ie want get called again.

but it always works... any better idea for how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in interface add variable & property:

```
NSMutableDictionary *earnedAchievementCache;

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSMutableDictionary *earnedAchievementCache;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize earnedAchievementCache;

- (void) submitAchievement: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (double) percentComplete
{




if(self.earnedAchievementCache == NULL)
{

    [GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)
     {
         if(error == NULL)
         {

             NSMutableDictionary* tempCache= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: [scores count]];
             for (GKAchievement* score in scores)
             {
                 [tempCache setObject: score forKey: score.identifier];
             }
             self.earnedAchievementCache= tempCache;
             [self submitAchievement: identifier percentComplete: percentComplete];
         }


     }];
}
else
{

    GKAchievement* achievement= [self.earnedAchievementCache objectForKey: identifier];
    if(achievement != NULL)
    {
        if((achievement.percentComplete >= 100.0) || (achievement.percentComplete >= percentComplete))
        {


            achievement= NULL;



        }
        achievement.percentComplete= percentComplete;
    }
    else
    {
        achievement= [[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier] autorelease];
        achievement.percentComplete= percentComplete;

        [self.earnedAchievementCache setObject: achievement forKey: achievement.identifier];
    }
    if(achievement!= NULL)
    {
        //Submit the Achievement...


        if (achievement.percentComplete>=100) {
           //show banner
            achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES; //only in IOS 5+
        }



[achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error)
         {
    if (error!=NULL){
            NSLog(@"Error!!");
    } else NSLog(@"all is well");

         }];
    }
}


}
```

in dealloc :

```
[self.earnedAchievementCache release];
```

i'm using the cache to not submit scores already submitted / completed

PS: the code is perfect just copy and paste it into your class and it will work

Comment: as far as I know, after iOS 5, game center caches the achievements automatically so every call of loadAchievements after the first one is instant.

Comment: i don't know about that...this method applies to all devices and that was what i was looking for at the time

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use in my helper Game Center class:

```
-(void) reportAchievementWithID:(NSString*) AchievementID {

[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *achievements, NSError *error) {

    if(error) NSLog(@"error");

    for (GKAchievement *ach in achievements) {
        if([ach.identifier isEqualToString:AchievementID]) { //already submitted
            NSLog(@"Already submitted");
            return ;
        }
    }

    GKAchievement *achievementToSend = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:AchievementID];
    achievementToSend.percentComplete = 100;
    achievementToSend.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
    [achievementToSend reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:NULL];

}];

}
```

note: I don't use percentages in my achievements, so you'd need to modify things a little bit if you do.